# Sinon Spy on all function calls within a function

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

Say we have a function like this in flow.js which is a web component so all are functions inside a class within this file.

```
change(){
   
   this.getParams();
   this.loadData();
}
```

I want to write a test case that can test change() and confirm whether these two functions have been invoked. I tried many approaches but it dint work. One of the approaches I tried is:

```
  it('change() test', function () {
     const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
     sandbox.spy(el);
     el.change();
     assert(el.change.calledOnce); // output is true
     assert(el.getParams.calledOnce); // output is false
     assert(el.loadData.calledOnce); // output is false
  }
```

el is the object/webcomponent.

Could you please let me know what is wrong here and what is the right implementation for this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add spy to `el.getParams()` and `el.loadData()` methods.

E.g.

`flow.js`:

```js
class Flow {
  change() {
    this.getParams();
    this.loadData();
  }
  getParams() {}
  loadData() {}
}

module.exports = Flow;
```

`flow.test.js`:

```js
const Flow = require('./flow');
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('flow', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    const flow = new Flow();
    sandbox.spy(flow, 'getParams');
    sandbox.spy(flow, 'loadData');
    flow.change();
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(flow.getParams);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(flow.loadData);
  });
});
```